# On a Pixel 6 with Android 12 and the March 5, 2022 security update, is it possible to change where you swipe up to unlock the phone?

Tags: lock-screens, android-12, google-pixel-6

This morning, I applied the March 5, 2022 security update to my phone. After this update and restart, I needed to change where I swipe up on the lock screen in order to bring up the PIN pad.

[image: lock screen]

Prior to this update - as last as last night - I used to place my finger on or near the lock icon and swipe up, as indicated by the green circle and arrow. However, after updating my phone to the latest patch, I now need to put my finger at the bottom edge of the screen and swipe up, as indicated by the red circle and arrow.

I may eventually get used to this, but right now, it's rather frustrating. I went through the settings related to swiping and the lock screen, but nothing seemed relevant. Enabling face or fingerprint unlock is not a viable option.

Is it possible to restore the original behavior? Is this this an intentional change and was it documented somehow?

Comment: I just tested on Pixel 3a, but looks like the position is irrelevant, only speed is the factor. Swiping up very slowly full to the top, even from the very bottom of the screen, will still fail. On the other hand, swiping up very fast from the lock icon will still successfully show the security option. Not sure if the Pixel 6 has a different behavior...

Comment: @AndrewT. It has a different behavior now. That was the pre-update behavior on the Pixel 6, as well. Speed may still matter, but location also matters a lot.

Comment: Something else that I've observed is that I can now long-press on the lock icon on the lock screen. I'm not sure if that was an existing feature that I just didn't know about.